# Python: In loop variable used within a statement not updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to write a piece of code that takes a string as input and replaces * for a range of numbers, sort of like:

I am * years old

0-10

I am 0 years old

I am 1 years old

...

This is an attempt to make my life easier on R while I also learn some Python.
Here is my code:

```
yourtext = input(" ")
number = input(" ")
number = int(number)

while number > 0:
    i = str(number)
    print(i)
    yourtext = yourtext.replace("*", i)
    print(yourtext)
    print(number)
    number = number - 1
```

And right now, this returns:

```
*
5 (my inputs)

5
5
5
4
5
4
3
5
3
2
5
2
1
5
1
```

So it seems like the i inside the replace function is fixed at its value on the first iteration of the loop. Why is this and how can I change it? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you make sure your indents are placed correctly for each line? Python is indent sensitive

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your question

Answer (score 1):

After you replace `*` with a number, the next iterations of the loop will do nothing. There are no more `*` in `yourtext`.

```
yourtext = yourtext.replace("*", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd ditch the `while` loop in favor of `for`, since you could get caught in an infinite loop that way. Also, `for` will take a range of values so you don't have to manually increment your value:

```
yourtext = input("What would you like? ")
number = int(input("What is the number? ")

if '*' not in yourtext:
    raise ValueError("could not find wildcard")

for i in range(number):
    print(yourtext.replace("*", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really close! Your only problem here is that the line:

```
yourtext = yourtext.replace("*", i)
```

is updating the yourtext variable. So after your first iteration through the loop, you've changed the "*" in yourtext to be the number. So instead of yourtext being the string "I am * years old" (in your original example) it gets changed to "I am 5 years old". Then, when you go through the loop again, there is no "*" to replace (because the string "I am 5 years old" has no *), so the text stays as "I am 5 years old" instead of changing to "I am 4 years old".

You can fix that by making a new temporary variable instead, for example replacing the problem line with:

```
updated_text = yourtext.replace("*", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the purpose of yourtext is, but after you replace the "*" the first time, yourtext will not update since it doesn't contain a * anymore. For example, if you input "test" instead of *, yourtext will never update because there is no * in the first place

```
4
test
4
3
test
3
2
test
2
1
test
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a `loop` with `string.replace()`

```
s = 'I am * years old'
number = 10

for i in range(number +1):
    print('{}'.format(s.replace('*', str(i))))
```

> ```
> I am 0 years old
> I am 1 years old
> I am 2 years old
> I am 3 years old
> I am 4 years old
> I am 5 years old
> I am 6 years old
> I am 7 years old
> I am 8 years old
> I am 9 years old
> I am 10 years old
> ```